# How to optimize join

Tags: sql, query-optimization, teradata

I am writing SQL like below. It is causing scanning of table "TBLA" every time which is a big table. I don't have any option to use indexing due to table design. How can i optimize the below one so that i don't have to scan tables again and again. Also I need to keep conditions for TBLB i.e. there are different condition for TBLB in each join. Appreciate any help

Thanks in advance :)

```
Sel SUB1.COLX,
    SUB1.COLY,
    SUB1.COLZ,
    SUB2.COLX,
    SUB2.COLY,
    SUB2.COLZ,
    SUB3.COLX,
    SUB3.COLY,
    SUB3.COLZ
FROM    
TBLA 
LEFT  JOIN
(SELECT COLX , COLY, COLZ FROM TBLB WHERE rec='123' )  SUB1
ON TBLA.SK=SUB1.SK
LEFT  JOIN
(SELECT COLX , COLY, COLZ FROM TBLB WHERE rec='456' )  SUB2
ON TBLA.SK=SUB2.SK
LEFT  JOIN
(SELECT COLX , COLY, COLZ FROM TBLB WHERE rec='789' )  SUB3
ON TBLA.SK=SUB3.SK
```

Comment: Sample data and expect results will help us help you, but it looks like you want a pivot/conditional aggregation?

Comment: Also, however, those `ON` clauses won't work. `SUB1`, for example, doesn't have a column `SK` defined.

Comment: Please post full DDL including indexes

Comment: @Larnu The method OP uses may be better if `TBLB` is very large and indexed on `(rec, SK)`, we need to see DDL first

Comment: SQL Server or Teradata? And it's actually the same table `TBLB` in those joins?

Comment: @Dnoeth.. Its Teradata

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag, please make sure you use the appropriate tags only.

Comment: Apologies everyone. I think my my questions were not clear. Actually I need specific column names from each join. I edited my original query. Is there any possibility of avoid multiple scans of same objects

Comment: Your select still makes no sense. You might want to PIVOT the data from TBLB *before* joining it.

Comment: I Agree Dnoeth. This is written by some developers in past.. Being a DBA I am not that good in query writing :)... I will check on how to make use of PIVOT

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, this should lower the query to a single scan/seek rather than 3. Tbhis does, however, *assume* that your lateral joins only return 1 row per value of `SK`:

```sql
SELECT {Table A Columns},
       oa.Sub1,
       oa.Sub2,
       oa.Sub3
FROM dbo.TableA A
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(CASE B.rec WHEN '123' THEN COLX END) AS Sub1, --If rec is actually a numerical datatype, don't wrap it in single quotes (')
                         MAX(CASE B.rec WHEN '456' THEN COLX END) AS Sub2, --If rec is actually a numerical datatype, don't wrap it in single quotes (')
                         MAX(CASE B.rec WHEN '789' THEN COLX END) AS Sub3  --If rec is actually a numerical datatype, don't wrap it in single quotes (')
                  FROM dbo.TableB B
                  WHERE B.SK = A.SK) oa;
```

Of course, you'll still need the relevant indexes here; for `TableB`, that would be on the column `SK` and `rec` and `COLX` would want to at least be in the `INCLUDE`.

Comment: Since OP now clarifies this is not SQL Server, this answer does not apply.

Comment: Unfortunate;y invalidating answers is also extremely frowned upon by the community, @Fred .

Answer (score 0):

If that's more or less your literal query, you are almost certainly getting product joins.  You are not specifying the correct alias in two of your joins:

```
LEFT  JOIN
(SELECT COLX FROM TBLB WHERE rec='456' )  SUB2
ON TBLA.SK=SUB1.SK
```

Also, there is no reason I can see to join to tblb 3 times.

```
Sel *
FROM    
TBLA 
LEFT  JOIN
(SELECT * FROM TBLB WHERE rec in ('123', '456', '789' )  SUB1
ON TBLA.SK=SUB1.SK
```